# Number of different colorings possible on a regular tetrahedron

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Find the number of different colorings of the faces of a regular tetrahedron with two white faces and two black faces.

I should use the Polya-Burnside Method of Enumeration to solve this since equivalent tetrahedrons can be attained through rotation. I have no idea how to start this problem, though. Any help would be great, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The rotation group of the tetrahedron is $A_4$, which acts $2$-transitively on the faces. All colorings with two white and two black faces are equivalent.

Comment: How do I use this to find the number of colorings? Thank you!

Comment: Are you counting rotation-equivalent colorings as the same? If so, it's $1$.

Comment: Ok, thanks @jmerry